# how to recompile a .lib in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, directx

I have a project that uses Effects11.lib and Effects11d.lib but when I build my project I get a bunch of "error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '__MSC_VER':value '1600' doesn't match value '1800'". And from what I have found, this is saying that the .lib was built for a different version of VS than what I am using and I need to recompile them. Issue is I am not sure how to do this. Never had to recompile a lib before.

Comment: You start with the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the authors site for this book @ http://www.d3dcoder.net/d3d11.htm, it looks like the Effects11.lib is Ms-Pl licensed source code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728664(v=vs.85).aspx

which then links to

https://fx11.codeplex.com/

which has a download for the source of that library at

https://fx11.codeplex.com/releases/view/150822

which seems to have project files which are buildable with VS2013 which you are using so you should be able to build effects.lib for vs2013 and continue with your development.

Alternative you could contact the author himself from his webpage and see if he can do this for you and link to it as its likely you're not the only one hitting this issue?

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have fixed my issue. I just have 1 other error to correct and then hopefully I can run my program.

Answer (score 0):

To recompile a .lib file, you first have to have the source code. You then open the vcproject of the library project, and then you change your settings and then you can recompile. I also found on the web that for some types of c++ in order to get it to recompile, you will have to delete the .o file generated in the library's directory. But, I do not know if that applies to your compiler. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: So how would I fix this error if all I have is the .lib files?

Comment: Um...I think then you cannot compile it without the source code. I  could be wrong though.

Comment: Try to see if you can get your hands on the source code. Everything will be much easier if you have it.

Comment: This is coming from the book "3D Game Programming With DreictX11" by Rank D. Luna. And the CD just has the .lib files. no source for the lib's

Answer (score 0):

Those static libraries are built with VS 2010, but you are using VS 2013. The link error is telling you that.

The fix in this case is to visit the Effects 11 site on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) and then build a fresh copy of the Effects 11 with your VS 2013 compiler. Alternatively, you can use the NuGet package [fx11_desktop_2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2013/) which is the same version built for VS 2013.

Note that as you are using VS 2013 which includes the Windows 8.1 SDK with the somewhat dated Luna book, you may be trying to make use of the deprecated D3DX11 library. You can certainly do that with VS 2013, but you have to make some adjustments to the project include/lib paths to get it to work. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). **The Effects 11 library version from CodePlex or NuGet has no dependencies at all on the legacy DirectX SDK.**

I have some general notes about that book [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx) as well.

For a complete list of D3DX11 alternatives, see [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).